# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/task/certificados/API_Certificado.crt'

Tags: nuxt.js, vercel

I am working on a Nuxt JS app using Vercel for a personal project. Now this works completely fine on my local. But when I am deploying it to Vercel, this error pops up.

Here is my code:

```
module.exports.getToken = async function (req, res) {
  const configDirectory = path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'certificados');

  const data = qs.stringify({
    client_id: process.env.inter_client_id,
    client_secret: process.env.inter_client_secret,
    scope: 'boleto-cobranca.read boleto-cobranca.write pagamento-boleto.read cob.write cob.read     pix.write pix.read webhook.read webhook.write payloadlocation.write payloadlocation.read',
    grant_type: 'client_credentials',
  });

  const config = {
    method: 'post',
    maxBodyLength: Infinity,
    url: 'https://cdpj.partners.bancointer.com.br/oauth/v2/token',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      },
      data: data,
      httpsAgent: new https.Agent({
        cert: fs.readFileSync(configDirectory + '/API_Certificado.crt'),
        key: fs.readFileSync(configDirectory + '/API_Chave.key'),
      }),
    };

   try {
     const response = await axios.request(config);
     res.status(200).json({
       token: response.data.access_token,
     });
   } catch (error) {
     console.log(error);
   }
}
```

I already tried [tutorial provided by Vercel](https://vercel.com/guides/loading-static-file-nextjs-api-route) but it didn't work.

The error message:

`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/task/certificados/API_Certificado.crt'"`

Can someone put up a solution? Thanks!

https://vercel.com/guides/loading-static-file-nextjs-api-route